# How can I read stderr when a command execution fails in Perl?

Tags: perl, external-process

I am executing a `diff` command in `perl`.

```
my @lines = `/usr/local/bin/diff -udr \"$expected_file\" \"$gen_file\"`;

if ($? != 0)
{
    print ERRFILE "Diff between $expected_file and $gen_file failed\n";
    return $diff_err;
}
```

Here the `diff` might have failed because of some reason. For example: the stderr showed that */usr/local/bin/diff: test.txt: No such file or directory*. I want to read this message in the program. How I can find the stderr message of the `diff` command (or `grep` or any command I execute)?

Appreciate the help in advance.

Thanks,
Mathew Liju

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is answered in [perlfaq8: How can I capture STDERR from an external command?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command)

If I want to read STDOUT and STDERR of a process, I use IPC::Open3, which comes with Perl. That way, I don't have to merge those streams and later figure out what part of the output came from what.

I would try to avoid temporary files whenever possible (so no `2>file.txt`). That's just too much work and code when I can read STDERR directly.

Answer (score 4):

There are several CPAN modules that make this easy and let you keep STDOUT and STDERR separate. For example, [IO::CaptureOutput](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::CaptureOutput) would let you do it like this (though you'll need to split the lines yourself):

```
use IO::CaptureOutput 'qxx';


my ($stdout, $stderr, $ok) = 
    qxx( qq(/usr/local/bin/diff -udr "$expected_file" "$gen_file") );

if (! $ok)
{
    print ERRFILE "Diff between $expected_file and $gen_file failed\n";
    return $stderr;
}

my @lines = split /\n/, $stdout;
```

-- David